# PHP/Regex - How to remove one from what found in a string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have

```
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
```

I want to decrease one unit from what was found in the text. So that the result should be

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
```

using `preg_replace`.

How can I do that?

**Edit**

I'm working on it at https://regex101.com.

Regex

```
(?:<br \/>){5}
```

and the text

`<p>1<br /><br />2<br /><br /><br />3<br /><br /><br /><br />4<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />5</p>.`

I wanted to put it in a loop and remove it from top to bottom. So first, it removes the `<br />` that is repeated 5 times then 4 then 3... . But that didn't work!

Comment: Have to tried anything? What is the logic here, does this only apply to repeated letters?

Comment: Can you update the question with that specific information? I think you increase the chance of getting a suited answer if you provide the most relevant information to the question with a failing pattern / attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a capture group 1 with a repeating backreference in group 2.

In the replacement use group 2, that has 1 occurrence less than that total match.

```
(<br />)(\1{1,4})
```

- `(<br />)` Capture **group 1**, match `(<br />` (Note that with a delimiter like `~` for the pattern you don't have to escape the backslash)
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\1{1,4}` Backreference to group 1, repetead 1-4 times
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZyDB7s/1)

```
$re = '~(<br />)(\1{1,4})~';
$str = '<p>1<br /><br />2<br /><br /><br />3<br /><br /><br /><br />4<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />5</p>';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$2', $str);
```

echo $result;

```
echo $result;
```

Output

```
<p>1<br />2<br /><br />3<br /><br /><br />4<br /><br /><br /><br />5</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a word-boundary between a digit and an angle bracket, so you can do that to remove the first `<br />` following each digit:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\b<br />~', '', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2z7h0/1)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```php
<?php

$data = ['aa',
'aaa',
'aaaa',
'aaaaa',
];

$newdata = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $newdata[] = preg_replace('/(.*).$/', '\1', $value);
}
var_dump($data, $newdata);
```

Comment: The array should be string.